# Javascript Read From Text File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filereader

I have recently gotten into html, css, and javascript and am writing a simple website. I need to have an autocomplete textbox. I have a textfile in the same folder as the html and need to read the textfile by newline in order to set the autocomplete sources (i can do that). What i can't do (yet) is get the file text.

I have seen examples with the `FileReader()` but all of them use the a file object like this.files[0] or from a `<input type=file>` object event. **How can I use a string for the file location ( "search.txt" ) and get the result?**

my code:

```
<body onload="ReadFile()">
<script>
    var data="";

    function ReadFile()
    {
        var fr=new FileReader();
        fr.readAsText("search.txt");
        data=fr.responseText;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The filereader is generally for uploaded files, if you need to fetch  a file from the server, use serverside code or XMLHttpRequest, and split the text file on newlines.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use XMLHttpRequest for all browsers and IE7+. However, for IE6 you need to use AciveXObject. You can use get or post request and parse the string after you receive the response from server.

var responseStr;
var xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET","search.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlhtpp.responseText will have the contents of the file. You  then further need to parse this.

Comment: when i tried this I got an error saying `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Documents/website/search.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.` btw, the site is not registered with a url, just a file on my computer. So i guess I have to use FileReader

Comment: you might want to use xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
     responseStr=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

Comment: if you are using XMLHttpRequest you cant use it  to issue request to other domains. the request needs to be made within the same domain.

Comment: so go with the FileReader() ? sorry im really new to this