# Get Random data in text fields from txt, csv on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a HTML text field 
for example I have list of names in txt or csv file
I want to call random name from list to that field on button click

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709482/how-to-read-text-file-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get HTML from a text file, you could use `AJAX`. What you're looking for is probably the `xmlHTTPRequest` method. It would look something like this

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET","search.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

You would then need to parse your file. My source is from this answer here

[Javascript Read From Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276478/javascript-read-from-text-file)

Let's say your html looks like this

```
<button id="my-button">Generate Random Names</button>

<input type="text" id="my-input" />
```

The first solution would be to query the button and input elements, and store the result in variables.

```
var button = document.getElementById("my-button");
var input = document.getElementById("my-input");
```

Let's say we store our names in a variable like this.

```
var names = ["Henry", "Joseph", "Mark", "Michael"];
```

You would then listen for the `click` event. And call your function. We can access individual elements in an array by listing the name of an array followed by the index of the element inside braces. We can now set the html of the input element to a random array element.

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    input.value = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
});
```

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/8nrpr5wn/

Comment: _I have list of names in txt or csv file_, where you get the data from file??!!

Comment: Dear Sir, I have more than 500+ names . is there any solution to get same data from csv or txt file

Comment: Thanks for your help.. It will also help me. (Respect)